# pdfpages, XeTeX, and transparency

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdfpages

I'm using `pdfpages` to include a cover made in Inkscape into a PDF. The PDF has transparent objects.

When building with `pdflatex`, the transparency is kept in the final PDF, but when I build with `xelatex`, I lose the transparency in the final PDF.

My cover PDF is http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/cover_fr.pdf

and a MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{cover_fr.pdf}
\end{document}
```

which generates http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/test_pdftex.pdf with `pdflatex` and http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/test_xetex.pdf with `xelatex`.

Am I missing an option? Is there a better way to include PDFs in XeTeX, or should I maybe convert it to a PNG instead?

**Edit:** I mean a *gradient*, not *transparency*. The original PDF has a yellow gradient behind the word "ou", which does not appear in the PDF generated with XeTeX.

**Note:** When I build, I have the following warnings:

```
** WARNING ** Version of PDF file (1.5) is newer than version limit specification.
```

Maybe I should export the PDF as 1.4 from Inkscape before importing it with XeTeX?

Comment: Redraw it in Tikz!

Comment: @Seamus: that's an option I have considered, but it would take muuuch longer ;-) Maybe I should try the Tikz export plugin for Inkscape...

Comment: It might be me, but I really didn't see any difference in the two pdfs you attached to your question...

Comment: I cannot see any transparency in your pdf `cover_fr.pdf`

Comment: @henrique, @Herbert: the yellow circle behind "ou" has a gradient that doesn't show with XeTeX but shows with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: I have no problem with pdflatex and xelatex ... TeXLive2010 under Linux. And I see no difference in your created pdf's when viewed with acroread

Comment: I can see (in adobe reader) the difference between your pdf's. The one from xetex is missing the yellow "mist" in the center. But I can't reproduce this with xetex from miktex 2.9. The output of pdftex + xetex are identical.

Comment: I'm using the standard TeXLive from Ubuntu Natty (TeXLive 2009). Maybe this was fixed in 2010?

Comment: @Raphink: Very likely. Several XeTeX from Ubuntu has several bugs that XeTeX from TL2010 doesn't have.

Comment: @Caramdir, I don't know if XeTeX is the problem, since both files looks exactly the same to me... Here's a screenshot I took with both PDF side by side (opened with evince): [screenshot hosted in imageshack, don't know for how long](http://img17.imageshack.us/i/screenia.jpg/)

Comment: @henrique: true, except that in Adobe Reader the XeTeX version has noticeably more saturation. Maybe a problam with certain versions of Adobe Reader?

Comment: I can't find Debian/Ubuntu packages for TL2010. Does anybody know where I can find some?

Comment: @Raphink There is sadly no texlive 2010 in the ubuntu package manager, but you can download it from the texlive homepage and install it manually. There is a guide on installation on the homepage as well. Btw because you mentioned the latex inkscape export in an earlier comment. This would not help here as pictures are always saved as pdf and simply text is exported as a tex file in order to match the document font in your latex document.

Comment: @Martin: I will have a look to see if it would be very time consuming to provide TL 2010 on my PPA. I've tested the Tikz export in Inkscape (which is actually native in my version of Inkscape) and indeed, it did not help at all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regenerated the PDF in Inkscape using PDF 1.4 and it fixed the problem.